# Why is it called "characteristic $0$" and not "characteristic $\infty$?"

Tags: ring-theory

There may not be a good answer to this; it is perhaps more or less a matter of coincidence. But the thing is: For any ring, the characteristic of the ring is the order of the element $1$ in the ring --- except if this order is $\infty$, in which case the characteristic is zero. So wouldn't it be more natural to call it characteristic $\infty$? Is there some smart reason behind this that I just haven't noticed yet, or is it just because mathematicians are weird?

Comment: I'm a mathematician myself, so I have the right to say it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is actually important is not the characteristic as a *number*, but the kernel of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to R$, as an *ideal*.

Since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, this kernel is always a principal ideal, so we can express what it is by quoting its (nonnegative) generator. This generator is what we call the characteristic of the ring.

For a characteristic-0 ring, the kernel is $\{0\} = \langle 0\rangle$.

(In some sense this is the root cause of a number of cases where zero "behaves like" an infinity in ring theory).

Comment: That's a good reason indeed!